# Cypress conditional assertions

Tags: javascript, cypress, assertion

I have a table which looks like this

```
1       /   2
abc     /    abc
abc     /    bca
abc     /    cda
```

Right now my code looks like this

```
cy.get('[role="row"]').each(($el) => {

            cy.get($el).children()
            .should('contain', 'abc')
          })
```

but how to check if second column contains one of (abc, bca, cda)
html is long as hell but in the middle it has something like aria-label = "abc"
Is regex good solution? Im not good at this could u tell me how it should look like (many attr at the beggining, aria-label = "abc" in the middle and some attributes at the end)? Or is there better solution?
Im dont know much anout js there is propably something wrong in my code below because first condition is always true and it shouldnt

```
cy.get($el).then(($try) => {
              if ($try.html('aria-label' == "abc")) {
                cy.log('it contains abc')}
              else if ($try.html('aria-label' == "bca")) {
                cy.log('it contains bca')}
              else if ($try.html('aria-label' == "bca")) {
                cy.log('it contains cda')}
              
              else{
                cy.log("DONT WORK")
              }
          })
                  }
```

Comment: Please add the html for your table.

Comment: Im sorry I cant because this is not my private project.

Answer (score 1):

This is assumption since I don't know how the html looks like. One way would be to use `expect(2).to.be.oneOf([1,2,3])`. I am assuming that you are validating the value of the attribute `aria-label`

```js
cy.get('[role="row"]').each(($el) => {
  expect($el.attr('aria-label').trim()).to.be.oneOf(['abc', 'bca', 'cda'])
})
```

In case you are checking the innerText of the element you can use:

```js
cy.get('[role="row"]').each(($el) => {
  expect($el.text().trim()).to.be.oneOf(['abc', 'bca', 'cda'])
})
```

Comment: I will give it a try. Thanks and sorry for inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

$try.html().includes('xxx') did the trick.